# Запрос к выпадающей странице через Python

Tags: python

Такая ситуация:пишу бота который должен заходить на сайт и нужно авторизоваться на сайте, но у сайта блок авторизации выпадает при наведении курсора на определенную область. Как это сделать через Python, но без использования браузера?

Comment: Посмотрите через инструменты браузера (F12) какой запрос отправляет при авторизации и повторите его

Comment: Вам нужно использовать Selenium. При его помощи вы сможете сделать то, что вам нужно.